# How to use Shader Editor for Grease Pencil Strokes and Fills

Tags: materials, node-editor

It seems that you can't use the shader editor (formally the node editor) to edit stroke and fills for the grease pencil. Am I mistaken, is there a way to edit these strokes and fills as you would a regular material?

Answer (score 4):

You can't, found this on the official documentation.

> The shader is not yet a BSDF capable shader to interact with Blender lights and can only be setting up on the Material Properties panel (it is not a shader node).
>   https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/materials/grease_pencil_shader.html

Hope they add it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I made a script that converts grease pencil strokes to mesh and it preserves the animation.

NOTE: the current version does not convert lines only loops and loops with hole using the subtract layer.
Current version is in alpha; save a lot so you don't lose progress.

[Shady_Pencil](https://github.com/ahkCodeder/Shady-Pencil/tree/Shady_Pencil-v1-alpha)